# Delete duplicate rows in textfile - except it contains a "{" or "}"

Tags: python

i have a very large textfile with contents like:

```
@INBOOK{Ackermann1999-b, 
  author = {Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, 
        K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. 
        and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and 
        Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, 
        K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. 
        and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and 
        Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, 
        K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. 
        and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and 
        Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann}, 
  year = {1980}, 
  timestamp = {1995-12-02} 
}
```

And i want to delete the duplicate rows except these rows containing the brackets { or }. 
The result should look like:

```
@INBOOK{Ackermann1999-b, 
  author = {Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, 
        Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann, K.-F. and Ackermann}, 
  year = {1980}, 
  timestamp = {1995-12-02} 
}
```

I come across with this Python-Skript, thanks to Vinay Sajip:

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen 
outfile = open("literatur_clean.txt", "w") 
for line in open("literatur_dupl.txt", "r"): 
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate 
        outfile.write(line) 
        lines_seen.add(line) 
outfile.close()
```

But it deletes also the lines with a closing bracket } and the lines with the same authordata. 
Therefor i need the condition of the brackets.

Could someone point me out to adding this condition?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ('{' in line or '}' in line) and line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
```

Comment: thanks eumiro, with a small modification "or" instead of "and" it works perfectly:
if ('{' in line or '}' in line) or line not in lines_seen: